# in SignalR run some logic before user will connect

Tags: .net, signalr

I am using .NET 6 and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` Framework (SignalR is included there)

I want to run some logic before client will connect to the `Hub`.(I want to have and use my own attribute like [Authorize] attribute). As I know In older versions of .NET there was `IHubFilter` but in ASP.NET Core 6 there is not something like this..

Comment: [`IHubFilter` is still present in ASP.NET Core 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.ihubfilter?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: thanks, I tried it bit it did not work and later I found out that I was missing `builder.Services.AddSignalR(options => options.AddFilter<CheckUserAttribute>());` in Program.cs.  (to use AddFilter method you should import namespace Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR )
if someone will need filters here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hub-filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0